# Unhandled Promise Rejection: RuntimeError: Out of bounds call_indirect (evaluating '(_main=Module["_main"]=wasmExports["ge"])(a0,a1)')

Tags: safari, emscripten

I have an application written in C++ which runs fine on Chrome and Firefox.

In Safari I saw this error on the console:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: RuntimeError: Out of bounds call_indirect (evaluating '(_main=Module["_main"]=wasmExports["ge"])(a0,a1)')

https://demo.carimbo.cloud

What can be?

Answer (score -1):

I had this error - only on Safari v17 and was able to fix it by reducing the number of parameters for the method being called.  9 was too many. 5 or 6 is ok.